# disable reactive form select form control in a form array

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, form-control, formarray

I am trying to disable a select form control by checking a condition in a reactive form and I could not do it dynamically in my form component. Was wondering if anybody did this before?

```
let control = <FormArray>this.scheduleForm.controls.schedulingAvailability;
this.scheduleObj.schedulingAvailability.forEach(x => {
  control.push(this.formBuilder.group({
    day: x.day,
    startTime: x.startTime,
    status: x.status
  }))
  if(x.status) {
    this.scheduleForm.get('x.startTime').enable();
  } else {
    this.scheduleForm.get('x.startTime').disable();
  }
})
```

And in my component, I have set-it up as following

```
<div formArrayName="schedulingAvailability">
    <div *ngFor="let d of scheduleForm.controls.schedulingAvailability.controls; let i=index">
        <div formGroupName="{{i}}">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-1">
                    <label class="checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" formControlName="status">
                        <span class="checkbox__input"></span>
                        <span class="checkbox__label">{{ scheduleObj.schedulingAvailability[i].day }}</span>
                    </label>
                </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <div class="form-group__text select">
                    <select formControlName="startTime">
```

Comment: What is the problem exactly? What does `I could not do it dynamically in my form component.` mean?

Comment: Sorry Alex, this is the error message - core.es5.js:1020 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'disable' of null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such variable as `this.scheduleForm.get('x.startTime')`. `startTime` is present in the formArray `schedulingAvailability`. So what you need to access that current index of the formarray in your iteration. So what you would do, is to change the `forEach` to a `for` loop instead, so that we can get the hold of the current index of the iteration:

```ts
let control = <FormArray>this.scheduleForm.controls.schedulingAvailability;

for (let i = 0; i < this.scheduleObj.schedulingAvailability.length; i++) {
  control.push(this.formBuilder.group({
    status: this.scheduleObj.schedulingAvailability[i].status,
    startTime: this.scheduleObj.schedulingAvailability[i].startTime
  }))

  // access the current formgroup of your formarray
  let fg = control.get([i])
  if (fg.get('status').value) {
    fg.get('startTime').enable();
  } else {
    fg.get('startTime').disable();
  }
}
```

### [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6e6vsw?file=app/app.component.ts)

Edit: As the value can be disabled, we need to remember that it's not included in the form values. So if you want to get the disabled values as well, use `this.scheduleForm.getRawValue()`